# Expanding vector norm into sum

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to expand a simple Euclidian vector norm into a sum of $x_i$ coefficients, so that for each $i$ term, I can treat everything as coefficients for a quadratic. I think I must have messed up somewhere because I get all sorts of weirdness in Matlab.

$\|Ax-b\|_2^2 = (Ax-b)'(Ax-b) = x'A'Ax -2b'Ax + b'b = \\
\sum_i \Big( [A'A]_{ii}x_i^2 - x_i (2b'A_i - \sum_{j \neq i} [A'A]_{ij}x_j)\Big) + b'b$

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong before I go nuts?

edit: $A_i$ is the i:th column of $A$

Comment: Out of curiosity why are you trying to do this?

Comment: For a variant on coordinate descent minimization. I want to minimize a function with respect to the $i$ coordinate, keeping the others constant.

Comment: Are $A,b,x$ real or complex? If they are real, then you are right. If complex, then you forgot the real part in $b'Ax$.

Comment: They're real here! Thanks for the reminder though, easy mistake to make.

Comment: Your second term must be : $(b'Ax + x'A'b)$ instead of  $2(b'Ax)$.

Comment: @DiffeoR: That's the same thing, you're just transposing a real number.